# Which Scheme is used in this paper?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am reading through "Three Implementation Models For Scheme". I want to work along and implement the interpreters but am getting error messages. I think the author is the man behind chez scheme, so I tried that in addition to DrRacket (R5RS mode). Does anyone know a scheme setup that will run this example code? Seems like this is a common problem with scheme. Every example code I try has some problem or was created in a different version. Here is a link to the paper. Thanks.

https://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs491/three-imp.pdf

Comment: Could you please be more specific. What is the error message you get, and the code that generates it.

Comment: In the interpreter on page 40 DrRacket(R5RS) does not like the '() in meta. It also complains about square brackets and (quote (obj) obj) on page 41. The message is just "Bad Syntax" or "illegal use of open square bracket".

Comment: I dont understand how it is possible to use Scheme keywords like "quote" and "lambda" in the meta evaluator. Isn't that always going to be a problem? Seems like you would need to quote them or something.

Comment: Don't use R5RS mode if you want to be able to use square brackets. Racket's R5RS compatibility mode is quite strict, and square brackets are not valid in R5RS. If you do want to use R5RS mode, then change all the square brackets to round brackets.

Comment: Yeah, That is an easy fix. Any idea on the others? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not strange that you get errors. The paper is written in 1987 and at that time the standard was R2RS (1985) until R3RS was released in November. It has been quite some changes from that to R5RS, which is the earliest version in actual use today so you won't find any modern Scheme that will run these examples unless it's only fundamental parts that has survived 4 revisions.

Eg. I see `rec` is used and it was mentioned removed in the [R2RS to R3RS changelog](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r3rs_10.html#SEC73).

The other changelogs are:

- [R3RS to R4RS](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r4rs_10.html#SEC75)
- [R4RS to R5RS](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs_10.html#SEC82)

Since many people follow SICP and it also is from R3RS era you might want to try the [SICP compability package](http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/) in DrRacket. When having the select in the lower left as "Determine language from source" you replace `#lang racket` with `#lang planet neil/sicp` and press <kbd>RUN</kbd>.

It will display some errors but just ignore it until it's finish and press <kbd>RUN</kbd> again. You now have a language that the SICP examples run which is closer to Kent Dybvigs language than modern R5RS.

Now SICP I guessed was R3RS, but [reading this thread](http://computer-programming-forum.com/40-scheme/a12ed45c2a9d58da.htm) I'm actually uncertain. It might happen that the compatibility pack only works for the SICP examples as well so it might be a bumpy ride still.

I think I have read half of every old paper about LISP dialects there are to understand the evolution of the language and how ideas came to be. I learned CL first, made my own LISP1 after reading [Paul Grahams essay about McCharty](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html). I read the lambda papers (the initial Scheme standard papers) and eventually watched [all SICP videoes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Op3QLzMgSY&list=PLD9319BC184C7FE27). When starting with R5RS I kept the online report close at all times since I did get errors, but it was kind of nice to know the history too.

Feel free to add questions as you go along, but add some info about it being an ancient Scheme and what you'd like it to work in.

Good Luck :)

Comment: What Scheme would you recommend I use to learn scheme while writing an interpreter then a compiler? Seems like every one recommends Racket. I don't really want to learn Racket, I want to stick with basic Scheme.

Comment: @MFlamer Answers to this is opinion based but since #!racket doesn't make mutation easy it wouldn't be easy to do some things in SICP  with it so I would use `#!r6rs`. I still recommend you use DrRacket though since it supports strict R6RS and R5RS and has a great macro expansion and debugger. Using R6RS or R5RS lets you use different implementations. Eg. I often use Ikarus to run my programs.  When you get a hang of it it's quite easy to learn `#!racket` as well. I sometimes write in `#!racket` for accessing the wast library and it's very similar to `r6rs` so the transition is quite easy.

Comment: @Sylwester Good old McCharty, the inventor of the ... flowchart? ;-)

Comment: @uselpa He invented LISP but there is not a single programming language out there that doesn't use any of his contributions to computer science and yes, conditionals are all his :)

Comment: @Sylwester That would be John McCarthy I guess ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Kent Dybvig defines `rec` in section 8.4 of his book *The Scheme Programming Language*, 3rd edition, using a `syntax-rules` macro from R5RS:

> `rec` is a syntactic extension that permits internally recursive
>   anonymous (not externally named) procedures to be created with minimal
>   effort.

```
(define-syntax rec
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ x e) (letrec ((x e)) x))))

> (map (rec sum
    (lambda (x)
      (if (= x 0)
          0
          (+ x (sum (- x 1))))))
  '(0 1 2 3 4 5))
(0 1 3 6 10 15)
```

Comment: A version of rec (actually, two versions of rec) is in SRFI-31 and pretty well supported by scheme implementations in consequence: http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-31/srfi-31.html

Answer (score 1):

Unless my memory fails me Dybvig used standard constructs only - except for record and record-case. You can find an implementation of record and record-case for Racket here:

http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2002-August/000290.html
http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2002-August/000292.html